# How can I protect against SQL injection attacks using Perl's DBI?

Tags: mysql, perl, sanitization

Is there a function i can use in Perl to sanitize input before putting it into a MySQL db?  I don't know regex very well so before I make my own function i was wondering if there was already one made.

Comment: Are you looking for `mysql_real_escape_string()`? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2207654/is-there-an-equivalent-of-phps-mysql-real-escape-string-for-perls-dbi/2207985#2207985

Comment: `mysql_real_escape_string` is a PHP function, not a Perl function

Answer (score 70, accepted):

The proper way to sanitize data for insertion into your database is to use [placeholders](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/DBI#Placeholders_and_Bind_Values) for all variables to be inserted into your SQL strings. In other words, NEVER do this:

```
my $sql = "INSERT INTO foo (bar, baz) VALUES ( $bar, $baz )";
```

Instead, use `?` placeholders:

```
my $sql = "INSERT INTO foo (bar, baz) VALUES ( ?, ? )";
```

And then pass the variables to be replaced when you execute the query:

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare( $sql );
$sth->execute( $bar, $baz );
```

You can combine these operations with some of the DBI convenience methods; the above can also be written:

```
$dbh->do( $sql, undef, $bar, $baz );
```

See the [DBI docs](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/DBI#Placeholders_and_Bind_Values) for more information.

Answer (score 22):

Minor (and admittedly pedantic) addendum to the "use placeholders" answers:  Parametrized queries are not, strictly speaking, "sanitizing".  They do not modify the data in any way to make it safe.  Instead, they protect against SQL injection by sending the query structure (commands) and the data by separate channels.

The reason I feel this distinction is significant is because treating sanitizing/quoting/escaping your data and using parametrized queries as the same thing implies that they are interchangeable or, at best, that parameters are just a better way to quote dangerous characters, so it's no big deal if you stick with quoting instead of bothering to figure out that placeholder stuff.

In truth, they are completely different techniques with completely different levels of reliability.  Quoting can provide *excellent* protection against injection, but there is always the chance that a determined attacker could find some corner case which will break or slip through your quoting algorithm and allow them to perform a successful SQL injection.  Parametrized queries, on the other hand, provide *absolute* protection against SQL injection.  Because the commands and data are sent separately, there is *no way* that the database engine can be tricked into executing data as a command.

Unless you're in a case where your language or database engine won't allow you to use a parameter in your query, *never* quote/escape/sanitize user input as protection against SQL injection.  *Always* use parametrized queries for this purpose if you are able to do so.

And the obligatory link:  http://bobby-tables.com/ has examples of how to use parametrized queries in several different languages, including Perl.

Comment: +1 Good explanation: When people come looking for `mysql_real_escape_string()`, we sort of know they have SQL injection in mind but a fully fleshed explanation is good to have. (incidentally, are there `mysql_fake_escape_string()` and `mysql_not_this_one_either_escape_string() as well?)

Answer (score 8):

In *very rare cases* you're not able to use placeholders, as described in other answers. But even in such rare case you shouldn't tamper with data by yourself, since it makes a place for a potential bug. It's better to use DBI's `quote` and `quote_identifier` methods. Also it makes your code less dependent on a particular RDBMS.

**Disclaimer.** The following is a dummy example and is not meant to illustrate the *very rare case* I mentioned.

```
$dbh->do('INSERT INTO ' . $dbh->quote_identifier($table) . ' (id, name) VALUES '
    '(NULL, ' . $dbh->quote($name) . ')');
```

Comment: How do you figure that using placeholders "makes your code... dependent on a particular RDBMS"? In working with PostgreSQL, MySQL, and SQLite, I have encountered differences between them, but, as far as I've seen, placeholders are handled identically by all three.  Are there any major RDBMS backends that don't support parametrized queries?  (Even if there are, I would expect the corresponding DBD driver to emulate them.)

Comment: You got me wrong. Placeholders are always alright. I compared using `quote` and `quote_identifier` against tampering with data by yourself, since various RDBMS have different quote characters.

Comment: Ah, OK.  Yes, I misread that statement as being an advantage of `->quote(_identifier)?` over placeholders, not over roll-your-own sanitizing regexes.

Answer (score 7):

How do you call the database?

[DBI](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/DBI) has support for prepared statements using [placeholders](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/DBI#Placeholders_and_Bind_Values). Both [DBIx::Class](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Class) and  [Rose::DB::Object](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Rose::DB::Object) sanitize values automatically, if you use the "find" method provided by each library.

Answer (score 0):

Answer: Use SQL placeholders (?).

Why: The structure of the SQL statement and the data values represented by the placeholders are sent to the database completely separately. so there is absolutely no way that the data values can be interpreted as SQL commands.