# In Perl, how do I properly quote string fragments I am using to build an SQL query?

Tags: sql, perl

I've a set of elements in an array which is read from a file.Now i want to use this array value in sql statement in `in Claus`!for that i need to enclose these string by '(single quote).so I've tried with for loop to do this! is there any way to do this same opp? like any in build functions like qw...
code:

```
open FILE, "<tab_name.txt" or die $!;
my @tab=<FILE>;
chomp(@tab);
@tab=split(",",$tab[0]);#set of like eg:$tab[0]=asc,cdf,sad,casd,aea,aee,asdf 
my @sql_str=();
foreach my $item(@tab){

        $item="'".$item."'";
        push(@sql_str,$item);#add comma
         push(@sql_str,",");
}
pop(@sql_str);#remove lase unwanted comma
```

i got the desired output like `'asc','cdf','sad','casd','aea','aee','asdf'` 
but is there any way to do this?

Comment: You shouldn't use quotation in values for SQL queries. Use placeholders instead.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to create a dynamic query using an IN clause.  If the number of values is fixed, create a template.  If the number of variables is not ocnstant, you will have to use the prepare statement and create and execute dynamic sql statment.  What db?

Comment: @jim:oracle db actually,'m trying to access this db via perl using sql plus

Comment: So, you end up with a full sql statement string like "select * from table where fld1 in ('foo', 'bar', 'junk');" ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/2207985/100754

Comment: See also Andy Lester's excellent resource, [Bobby-Tables.com](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may works:

```
my $sql_str = join ',' => map { $_ = qq|'$_'|; } @tab;
```

But, manually building your SQL this way is a **bad idea™**. [Parameter binding](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2207654/100754) is the proper way to solve this problem.

Comment: If You use `$_ =` in `map` then it is edited inplace, so the `@tab =` is not needed.

Comment: @TrueY, thanks. Updated my answer with your suggestion

Comment: This `=>` is a kind of tricky, but `,` is enough. The `$_ = ` is not really needed (except You really want to modify `@tab` as well)

Comment: @Miguel:good job dude

Answer (score 3):

Do You need an array, or a string fr the `in` clasue? I assume a string is proper, so what about this?

```
my $sql_str = join ",", map { $dbh->quote $_ } split ",", $tab[0];
```

But `Miguel Prz` is right, You should use [parameter binding](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/linux/dbi/ch05_03.htm) instead! This will save Your Oracle server for parsing over and over again the same SQL statements.

Other minor issue. If You use `my @tab=<FILE>;` it will read the whole file. But in the code only the first line is used. So You could use `my $tab = <FILE>;` to read only the first line.

Comment: If you have a database handle, `map { $dbh->quote($_) }` instead of `map { "'$_'" }` to properly handle quotes inside `$_`.

Comment: @Stefan Majewsky: Thanks, corrected.

Answer (score 3):

To do this with placeholders (i.e., properly), you need to first gather all the values for the `IN` clause into a single array (`@values`) so that you know how many of them there are, then:

```
my $in_clause = join(', ', ('?') x scalar @values);
my $sql_str = "select field1, field2 from my_table where id in ( $in_clause )";
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql_str);
$sth->execute(@values);
```

(`scalar` isn't strictly necessary here, but included to make it a little more obvious what's going on for the OP.)